# Get value from input in modal returning empty string

Tags: jquery, angular, typescript

I am using ng-multiselect-dropdown in my bootstrap modal so the user can select multiple products, and in every `onItemSelect` I am inserting a new div with jquery method `insertAfter()` which will receive the amount of the chosen product. 
For that I am creating a fresh new id for every div starting with 'p' and adding the product id (idProduto) to it, so I can delete it onItemDeselect and get the inputted value using jquery's `val()`.

The error is on getting the value of the field, it is returning an empty string.

onItemSelect method

```
onItemSelect(item: any){
    if (item){
      this.itemCompra = item;
      $('<div id="p'+this.itemCompra.idProduto+'" class="form-group"><label for="exampleFormControlInput1">Quantidade de '+this.itemCompra.nome+'</label><input id="p'+this.itemCompra.idProduto+'" class="form-control" formControlName="quantidade" type="number" min="1" [(ngModel)]="compra.quantidade'+this.itemCompra.idProduto+'" [ngClass]="{ '+!this.inv+' : submitted && f.quantidade.errors }"><div *ngIf="submitted && f.quantidade.errors" class="invalid-feedback"><div *ngIf="f.quantidade.errors.required">Escolha a quantidade</div></div></div>').insertAfter('#bodyCompra form>div:last');
      this.cont++;
    }
 }
```

I am trying to get the value to use it in another function. this is a console log to show you how i am trying to get the value in a for loop:

```
while(i<this.compra.ps.length){
  console.log($('#p'+this.compra.ps[i]["idProduto"]).val());
  //this.compra.ps[i]["quantidade"]=$('#p'+this.compra.ps[i]["idProduto"]).val();
  i++;
}
```

`this.compra.ps` is an array I am getting from my template using `[(ngModel)]`

Comment: Solved!!! I had 2 ```id```'s with the same name, that is why my ```val()``` was returning an empty string. I just changed the 2nd one and it is working fine now.

Comment: why on earth are you using jQuery with angular?

Comment: My supervisor recommended and i am enjoying learning it. Shouldn't I use it?

Comment: It isn't really recommended to use anything that manipulates the DOM in Angular. Angular isn't aware of what happens when you for example manipulate DOM with jQuery. So you can run into lots of trouble when doing that. Manipulating the DOM in Angular should be the **last resort**. But 99% of the time there is an "Angular way" to do things instead of using for example jQuery.

Comment: Even the documentation on `ElementRef` (though you are not using it here, but it is one way to access the DOM) warns you to just use that only when needed: https://angular.io/api/core/ElementRef#description

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!!! I had 2 id's with the same name, that is why my val() was returning an empty string. I just changed the 2nd one and it is working fine now.